# SVG does not line up correctly with aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been trying to solve this for a while now and can't get the SVGs to align correctly for some `width` and `height`. My `viewBox` has `16:9` aspect ratio and I would like to scale the SVG by the same aspect ratio. For some `width` and `height`, it does line correctly but for others it doesn't although both have the same aspect ratio.

Any hints on what is causing this?

I have a JSFiddle for you to try, https://jsfiddle.net/n90ty8ys/1/

```html
<svg id="svg-main-panel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 768 432" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="1120" height="630">
  <rect xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="blue"></rect>
  <svg width="20" height="40" x="20" y="20">
    <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="657.247" y1="172.823" x2="657.247" y2="152.907" gradientTransform="rotate(90 405.13 -232.117)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4"></stop>
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#a)" d="M20 0H.034L0 40h19.966"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" x="20" y="60">
    <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19.775" y1="30" x2="-.14" y2="30">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#a)" d="M-.034 20h20v20h-20z" />
    <linearGradient id="b" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1207.701" y1="556.747" x2="-1207.701" y2="576.663" gradientTransform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 576.556 -1188.2)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#b)" d="M0 40l19.966-20L20-1H0" />
    <linearGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-847.237" y1="1808.924" x2="-847.237" y2="1828.84" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 -826.737 -1788.733)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#c)" d="M41 40V20H19.934L0 40h19.968" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

[image: does not line up]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updates

Originally I thought viewBox and svg had different ratio, which actually had the same. I updated #2 below accordingly.

---

I see two potential issues:

1. Your `<path>` elements have decimal numbers in `d` attribute. As browsers rendering unit is pixel (integer), it might misalign your SVG elements. In the below snippet, I changed all the decimal numbers in `d` attributes to integers. For example, I changed `<path fill="url(#c)" d="M41 40V20H19.934L0 40h19.968" />` to `<path fill="url(#c)" d="M41 40V20H20L0 40h20" />`.
2. Your base `<svg>`’s `viewBox` size, especially ratio, is different from `width` and `height` attribute value. <s>Your viewBox width and height is `768` and `432` respectively, while your `<svg>` has `width="1120" height="630"` for its size value. That difference makes the SVG skewed unexpectedly and might produce decimal-based rendering that causes pixel misalignment in the browser.</s> As `viewBox` vs `<svg>` size ratio is 1:1.46 (1120/768), it could render misaligned elements. There is a [great article](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) by Sara Soueidan about how to configure your viewBox numbers.

I applied those two changes in the snippet below, and it seems to work fine. Good luck!

```html
<svg id="svg-main-panel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1120 630" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="1120" height="630">
  <rect xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="blue"></rect>
  <svg width="20" height="40" x="20" y="20">
    <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="657.247" y1="172.823" x2="657.247" y2="152.907" gradientTransform="rotate(90 405.13 -232.117)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4"></stop>
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#a)" d="M20 0H0L0 40h20"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" x="20" y="60">
    <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19.775" y1="30" x2="-.14" y2="30">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#a)" d="M0 20h20v20h-20z" />
    <linearGradient id="b" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1207.701" y1="556.747" x2="-1207.701" y2="576.663" gradientTransform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 576.556 -1188.2)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#b)" d="M0 40l20-20L20-1H0" />
    <linearGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-847.237" y1="1808.924" x2="-847.237" y2="1828.84" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 -826.737 -1788.733)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#EBF0F2" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BDCCD4" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#c)" d="M41 40V20H20L0 40h20" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: You're right on the first one. I am not sure about the second one. I can make them align perfectly if I match values in `viewBox` with `width` and `height`. I would like to make my `viewBox` values stay and only changing `width` so that it scales based on the ratio of my `viewBox` values. Right now my `viewBox` has value of `768x432` which is `16:9`, even if I specify the `width` and `height` to be `1120x630`, that is still `16:9`, so there shouldn't be any decimal point.

Comment: Regarding #2, you are stretching your 768px viewBox to 1120px. It means 1px will be stretched to about 1.46px (1120/768 = 1.458333). That might produce misalignment. Try `viewBox='0 0 560 315'` which is exactly half of the svg size, and I think it will not break as it makes 1px scaled up to 2px.

Comment: You're right they have same ratio. I originally misunderstood they had different size ratio. However, it still can cause misalignment. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for the heads-up.